# Efficiently sort subset of the vector that defines the order

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

I have the vector that defines the order of items (0..N-1), e.g.
`{5, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 6}`.

I have to sort subsets of that vector. So, for `{0, 1, 2, 5}` I should get `{5, 0, 2, 1}`.

I tested the following solutions:

1. Create a set of items in a subset, then clear the subset, go through the ordering vector, adding only items in the set.
2. Create new sorted vector by going through the ordering vector, adding only items found by in the subset by `std::lower_bound`.

The second solution seems much faster, although it needs subset to be sorted. Are there any better solutions? I am using C++/STL/Qt, but the problem is probably not language-dependent.

Comment: If you are going to sort many small subsets, it would be worth it to build a vector that, for each item, gives its position: {1,5,4,3,2,0,7,6}. Then you can call std::sort using a comparison functor that does a lookup in that vector.

Comment: [Example of Marc's suggestion](http://ideone.com/OO51IF). (uptick btw, Marc; you should consider posting that as a plausible answer).

Comment: Yes, this is probably a better way of storing sort vector, as it makes the code easier. However, this is still O(n long n) on average - I wonder if there is a way to make it faster.

Comment: @Michal going from a complexity that depends on N and n to one that only depends on n already seems like a big win to me... Then if that's not enough for you, nothing prevents you from replacing std::sort with a radix sort or any other sort specialized for small integers, the main point is that you can forget about the ordering vector, using the lookup reduces the problem to regular sorting, which is abundantly documented.

Comment: I would like to accept Marc's answer but he added it as a comment. Is there a way to move it to answer?

Comment: @Michal when you manage to solve your problem, it is fine to write your own answer explaining how you fixed it. Crediting someone (just mention their name anywhere, don't forget WhozCraig for the code sample) if their comment helped is nice. Having the answer spelled in the OP's own words may make it more useful / accessible to whoever finds it through google.

Comment: @Marc Glisse I went for your solution - I keep the vector which stores the position of each item. The only change I did is to have a special value in case items are in default order (which is quite common). In that case I don't create {0, 1, 2, 3, ...} vector, but use default comparison instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


    struct cmp_subset
    {
        std::vector<int> vorder;

        cmp_subset(const std::vector<int>& order)
        {
            vorder.resize(order.size());
            for (int i=0; i<order.size(); ++i)
                vorder.at(order[i]) = i;
        }

        bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const
        {
            return vorder[lhs] < vorder[rhs];
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<int> order = {5, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 6};
        std::vector<int> subset = {0, 1, 2, 5};

        for (auto x : subset)
            std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';

        std::sort(subset.begin(), subset.end(), cmp_subset(order));

        for (auto x : subset)
            std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';

        return 0;
    }
```

The code is copied from [here](http://ideone.com/OO51IF)

Comment: This solution was first suggested by Marc Glisse in the comments section.